# How can i get the default login mail id in ios programmatically?

Tags: ios, email, default

i want ot send the images from email id which was defaultly set in the iOS device.Through that email id i want to send the images to the another people.is it possible?Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the iOS SDK doesn't expose that information publicly. You must use a custom interface to ask user's email. Or use [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/) class.